# VBA Chart: Ranges until last non-empty row as source data

Tags: vba, excel, charts

So I have a spreadsheet with data spanning A2 to AF17, I hid the majority of columns such that now only columns: I, AB, AD, AF are showing, where column I is the range I want as axis labels range, and column AF as the value range.

I coded the following to create a graph that dynamically uses range until last non-empty row as Values:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim MyEmbeddedChart As Chart

Set MyEmbeddedChart = Sheets("Analysis").Shapes.AddChart(Width:=634, Height:=250).Chart

With MyEmbeddedChart
    .ChartType = xlBarClustered
    .ChartStyle = 339
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Analysis").Range("AF2", Cells(Rows.Count,  1).End(xlUp))
    .Legend.Delete
    .Axes(xlValue).Delete
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .ApplyDataLabels
End With

End Sub
```

Now even though the resulting graph automatically shows column I as axis labels range, it is only because column I is the leftmost visible column right now. That is, in actuality the source data range is A2:AF17, and the axis labels range is actually A2:AD17. And as soon as I unhide the columns, naturally the axis labels got messed up.

Even though the current graph serves my purpose, it is definitely not ideal. So how do I set the source data to be precisely column I as the axis label range and column AF as the value range while keep using the last non-empty row method?

I am still relatively new to VBA, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use the `ChartObject` instead of the `Chart`, I find it easier to nest underneath for all properties, than to use `Chart.Parent`.

The code below will create your chart, and afterwards it adds a `Series` with defined `Range` (fully qualified `Range`) for `Values`, and Column "I" as the `Range` for `XValues` (X-Axis).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim MyEmbeddedChart As ChartObject
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = Worksheets("Analysis")

Set MyEmbeddedChart = Sht.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 634, 250)

With MyEmbeddedChart
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .ChartStyle = 339
        .Legend.Delete
        .Axes(xlValue).Delete
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .ApplyDataLabels
    End With

    ' this is for one series , you need to do this for every series collection
    With .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "ser" & MyEmbeddedChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        .Values = Sht.Range("AF2", Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp))
        .XValues = Sht.Range("I2", Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    End With
End With

End Sub
```